# How to prevent second click on radio button if it is already checked so that javascript event can be prevented

Tags: javascript

How to prevent second click on radio button if it is already checked so that javascript event can be prevented.

As I am doing many things onclick of radio button

```
<input name="EnumEvent" type="radio" value="Open" onclick="show_event()"/>
```

javascript

```
function show_event()
{
    document.getElementById("radio-btns-div1").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById('invited').style.display="none";
    document.getElementById('invited').value = '';
    document.getElementById('invite_1').value='';
}
```

Comment: you mean `Disable` radiobutton after clicking ?

Comment: Fabrizio Calderan now have a look at the code. You would get a better idea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use change event instead of click

```
<input name="EnumEvent" type="radio" value="Open" onchange="show_event()"/>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LHkpH/)**

Comment: This does not prevent the user from selecting another option, and then perhaps change back again. but it does protect from "double-click"

Comment: @fredrik: so far I understand from the question, he only wants to prevent event handler to be executed when selected radio button is clicked.

Comment: You are right that that is what the question asks for. But I've seen many instances of question where the person asking didn't quite know beforehand there there could be followup problems. So I thought it worth mentioning that. Your answer is 100% correct for what he wrote in the question - but in 5min, when he tries it, he might notice that he also wanted the user to be unable to press any option.

Answer (score 1):

Add the disabled attribute

```
function show_event()
{
  document.getElementByName("EnumEvent").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
  ...
}
```

Don't forget to remove the attribute when/if you want the user to be allowed to select another option.

Comment: This was just the direction that I needed, I ended up using this code:

`document.getElementsByName(radioName).forEach((radio)=>{ radio.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled"); }); `

Answer (score 0):

```
var clicked = false;
$('input:radio.yourclass').click(function(event){
     if (clicked){
         event.preventDefault();
     }
     clicked = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Clicked() {
if (document.getElementById("radio-btns-div1").checked) {

document.getElementById("radio-btns-div1").disabled = true;
}
```

Refer to [Disable radio button according to selected choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739514/disable-radio-button-according-to-selected-choice)